# Trying to enable swipe left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe, hammer.js

The following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.min.js"> </script>

<script>

    Hammer($(document)).on("swipeleft", function() 
    { 
        alert("Swipe Left"); 
    });

</script>
```

And I do not see "Swipe Left" alert. What is wrong?

Comment: Try `Hammer(document.body).on(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, Document is too generic. You need to have an object that you are swiping on:

For Example, this performs an action when you swipe left on a DIV with the ID of box1.

```
<div id="box1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">SOME TEST</div>

<script>
$(function(){  
  var objbox1 = document.getElementById("box1");

  //Swipe
  Hammer(objbox1).on("swipeleft", function() {
        alert('Swiped Left');
    });
});
</script>
```